# How does compiler read this: someString.indexOf(someOtherString.charAt(0))?

Tags: java

Perhaps my confusion stems from an unclear understand of how the indexOf class works. I understand that someString.indexOf(3) will return the letter of index 3 in the string someString. I also understand how someOtherString. charAt(3) works. But if you combine them like someString.indexOf(someOtherString.charAt(5)), what is happening?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! This question is liable to **downvotes** as the question body is poorly formatted and you didn't provide any example string. Urgent attention is needed! - please edit this question and reply!

Comment: Do not post the same question again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I understand that `someString.indexOf(3)` will return the letter of index 3 in the string `someString`.

No it doesn't. It returns the index of the character whose binary value is 3 in `someString`. This expression is very likely to be a programming error, as you wouldn't normally be passing `chars` around as `int` constants.

> I also understand how someOtherString. charAt(3) works.

Let's see. It returns the character at index 3 (that is to say the fourth character, because of zero-based indexing).

> But if you combine them like `someString.indexOf(someOtherString.charAt(5))`

This is not combining them. This is a different expression entirely. There is nothing here resembling `someString.indexOf(3)`.

> what is happening?

It returns the index in `someString` of the character at index 3 in `someOtherString`. So clearly the `charAt()` part must be evaluated first.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler will split it up into tokens. The tokens in the string you provided would be `someString`, `.`, `indexOf`, `(`, `someOtherString`, `.`, `charAt`, `(`, `0`, `)`, `)`.

Once it has been tokenized it needs to generate and Abstract Syntax Tree (AST). This will break it down into names, groupings, operators, and literalls. Names are things like variables, class names, and keywords. Groupings are usually broken down by parentheses `()`. Operators are mathematical, logical, bit wise, and separators; some examples are `.,+=^*|`. Literalls are things like numbers and strings.

After the compiler has an AST it will start generating the bytecode. This will start identifying all of things we see in code. Some of the things are variables declaration, modification, and access; types; operators (again); method calls; and a few other things.

Then the compiler verifies the code. This includes things like validating variables, method calls, operator usage, etc.

Once the bytecode is validated it exported into a class file.